# Quickly locating error message in MSCV 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ide, compiler-errors

When I compile my C++ project and have errors, to see those errors I need to open a find window 
and search for 'error' inside the output window.

Isn't any better way to go over the error messages?

Thank you

Comment: Can you not just click on the error messages in the Error List window to be brought straight to the relevant line in the code?

Comment: Getting to the error message is my problem - how can I get there without searching in the output box for 'error' string?

Comment: From within Visual Studio, click View->Error List to make sure the Error List window is visible then try building your project. If there are errors then they should be clickable from within that window once the project compilation has failed.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know that... more the 2 years now ***k!

Comment: Glad it turned out to be something simple. I have added my comment as an answer, that way you can close off this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment from earlier, the Error List window can be shown by clicking View->Error List from the main menu or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>.

With the Error List window visible any errors detected during compilation should be clickable from within that window once the compilation has failed.

[image: Error List]